# After closing on my house I found out the listing and emails misrepresented facts, do I have a legal recourse against the seller?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, michigan

Since taking possession of the house on 27 May we discovered the follow information regarding exaggeration/misrepresentation.

1. The listing stated “Lake access with permission for docking a boat from EGLE/DNR across the street”.  In our research we found that EGLE has no record of permission for a dock at the road end.  Furthermore, EGLE has stated that they prohibit the installation of docks at the public road ends unless it is done by the local government or the property owner has deeded access and that either way, a permit is still required from EGLE.  We attest the seller/realtor (representing herself) knew there was no permission for a dock and made the false claim because the law was never enforced.
2. In email correspondence with our realtor we asked if the boat could be left in over night or if needed to be removed everyday.  The seller/realtor replied “We can leave the boat there all summer, you don't have to take it out every day. That is a bonus right there.” In our research we found that per Michigan Compiled Laws at [MCLA 324.30111b](https://www.animallaw.info/statute/mi-habitat-protection-chapter-324-natural-resources-and-environmental-protection-act#s30111b) docking a boat between 12 midnight and sunrise or installing a seasonal dock without a permit is a misdemeanor.  We attest the seller/realtor knew of this law based on you not disclosing a dispute regarding the dock between neighbors until after all closing paper was signed and accepted.  In the dispute written correspondence provided it calls out MCLA 324.30111b and seller/realtor by name.

Comment: You don’t say what jurisdiction this is in. Without that information, you won’t get a useful answer.  You need to consult a lawyer about what’s considered “fraud” and what’s considered “due diligence” there.

Comment: What does this mean: "*In the dispute written correspondence provided it calls out MCLA 324.30111b and seller/realtor by name.*"?

Comment: @Rick There's an existing dispute between the previous property owners and the neighbors about a seasonal dock and/or boat which wasn't disclosed to the buyers'. The correpondence from the dispute calls out a Michigan law so the owners/realtor should not have made misleading/incorrect statements to the prospective buyers.

Comment: OP, please edit in more information to your question about the details like the pre-existing dispute.

Comment: "Lake access with permission for docking a boat from EGLE/DNR" Does this mean you *need* permission, or you *have* permission?